# Using Java RMI, why does a remote method call yield the client's timezone instead of the server's?

Tags: java, server, timezone, client, rmi

I'm trying to grasp the basics of Java RMI.

The idea is to have two separate processes running, each primed by a separate main in one of two classes:

- `Client` running as a client
- `Server` running as a server

A third class `Document` acts as the shared object (it being a simple collector of `Strings`), with its method `addTimestamp()` saving the current `Timestamp` for further printing in the console. This method is also one available as a remote method, as defined in `DocumentInterface`.

Executing the two mains on two different `cmd` windows yields a perfectly functioning system:

- `Server`: `java -cp rmi.jar Server`
- `Client`: `java -cp rmi.jar Client`

As expected the client's output is:

> CLIENT - Viewed on: 2016.09.30 01.53.01
>
> SERVER - Viewed on: 2016.09.30 01.53.01

When I start the server under a different timezone though:

- `Server`: `java -Duser.timezone=PST -cp rmi.jar Server`
- `Client`: `java -cp rmi.jar Client`

I still get the original client output:

> CLIENT - Viewed on: 2016.09.30 01.53.01
>
> SERVER - Viewed on: 2016.09.30 01.53.01

I would expect the second line to have the server's PST-based `Timestamp`. I checked the flag was set correctly by having it printed directly by the server's main, and it is indeed different:

> 2016.09.29 16.55.57

From what I've understood so far, when calling the `addTimestamp()` method remotely on the remote object:

- the current `Document` is passed by copy to the server
- the `Timezone` is appended by the server, using its instance of the `Document` class
- the returned `Document` is passed by copy back to the client
- the `Document` is displayed by the client

In this case I would thus expect that `Timezone` to be based on the server's settings, not the client's. Why is this not the case?

Here are some code snippets from the four classes:

*Document.java*:

```
public Document addTimestamp(Document document) throws RemoteException
    {
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());

    document.strings.add("Viewed on: "+timestamp);

    return document;
    }
```

*DocumentInterface.java*:

```
public interface DocumentInterface extends Remote
    {
    public Document addTimestamp(Document document) throws RemoteException;
    }
```

*Server.java* - `main`:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
Document document = new Document();
Naming.bind("rmi:///Document", document);
```

*Client.java* - `main`:

```
Document document = new Document();
DocumentInterface remoteDocument;
try
    {
    remoteDocument = (DocumentInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi:///Document");

    document.addString("USER - ");
    document.addTimestamp(document);
    document.addString("\n");
    document.addString("SERVER - ");
    document = remoteDocument.addTimestamp(document);

    System.out.println(document.toString());
    }
catch (Exception except)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Can you print the time inside addTimestamp, and check whether it runs on the client or the server (by which window it gets printed in)?

Comment: It's getting printed in the client's window! Why is that?

Comment: Because it's running on the client. Now, I don't know *why* it's running on the client...

Answer (score 1):

Because `Document` is an exported remote object, it is running as a callback at the client. Not by copy at the server.

Remove the remote interface and `extends UnicastRemoteObject`, and make it serializable.

Comment: Thanks, this explains it. If I remove the `Remote` interface, I cannot bind it to the rmi registry anymore though (the binded object must be of type `Remote`). How can I have a `Document` binded by the server so that it can be called by the client, and also not have it behave like a callback?

Comment: You need to make up your mind as to whether you're creating a new Document at the client or looking it up in the Registry. At present you're doing both. Normally this wouldn't be possible, as you wouldn't have the `Document` remote object class even present at the client.

Comment: What I'd like to do is have the client look in the registry for a binded `Document`, and have the server execute the remote method so that it displays the server's time. I'd then use the client `Document`  to display everything, and that that same method ran locally gives a different timestamp.

Comment: So if you use the client's Document it will execute at the client. You have a serious mixup here. Only you can resolve it.

Comment: Bear with me, I'm rusty in Java. Am I not calling the method on the server here: `document = remoteDocument.addTimestamp(document);`? The way I see it, I'm passing the client's `document` to the server's rmi binded `remoteDocument`, and that instance then runs `addTimestamp`. Being on the server, I'd expect the returned `document` to have the server's timestamp. What is happening instead is that the method is called on the client instead of on the server.

Comment: Step back a moment. Why does the `addTimestamp()` method take a `Document` parameter? instead of a timestamp? Which document are you adding a timestamp to? Clarify your thinking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124707/discussion-between-gliptal-and-ejp).

Comment: Forget it. I'm going away for a week tomorrow. You need to answer the questions I asked, *to yourself.* What you have at the moment is a totally confused API design. Rationalize it.